# Filtering in Django html template

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I'm passing two models into the html template

listings - has all the properties of the listed items (like on an auction site)

bids - has a listing field as a foreign key to link to listings (and the user who made a bit, plus the amount)

I'm looping through the listings items to display all their attributes of the individual listings on cards (that works nicely)
I want to display the bid that belongs to the individual listing if there is any (only the highest bid is passed on for each listing in the 'bid' queryset)

I suspect the problem is with the syntax here, but can't find a solution.

`<p>{{bids.filter(listingID=listing.listingID)}}</p>`

The error message:
*Could not parse the remainder: '(listingID=listing.listingID)' from 'bids.filter(listingID=listing.listingID)'*

This is my HTML template

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>
    <div></div>
    {%for listing in listings%}
        <div class="listingItem">
            <div class="listingLeft">
                <a href={{listing.id}}><img class="listingImage" src="{{listing.listingImage}}"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="listingRight">
                <a href={{listing.id}}><h4>{{listing.listingName}}</h4></a>
                <p>{{listing.listingDesc}}</p>
                <p>Current bid: ${{listing.listingFirstBid}}</p>
                <p>{{bids.filter(listingID=listing.listingID)}}</p>
                <p class="created">Created: {{listing.listingCreated}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should do all that filtering etc. in the view. Django does not support calling functions / indexing (`object[something]`), more python syntax etc. It aims to separate logic and design.

Comment: Also you can simply loop over related fields. Assuming bid has a foreign key to listing, you can write something like `{% for bid in listing.bid_set.all %}` Assuming the model name of a bid is `Bid` and you set no related name.